# Sybase change name for the Database

Tags: java, sybase, powerdesigner

I need to change name for the Database. Strange but it is specified the data type as User
I am trying to to do that:

```
new User(raw.GetChildren().Item(3)).SetNameAndCode("____"+system+"_raw",system+"_raw"))
```

But this is not a good solution to go in this was as. Is there is a method to do something like
model.GetUsers()?

Comment: There seems to be a GetUsers on PdPDM.BasePhysicalModel.

Comment: @pascal I am not using BasePhysicalModel. I am using just the Model

Comment: I'm only using vbscript to work with PowerDesigner, so I don't exactly if it works. But from the Java sample, it seems you can convert the model reference into the proper class with something like this
Model aModel = null;
if (pdApp.GetActiveModel().IsKindOf(PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model)) {
  // Convert the active model to an OOM model proxy object
  aModel = new Model(pdApp.GetActiveModel());